# Definition of Martin kernels

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, potential-theory, green-function

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ $(n \ge 3)$ be a bounded $C^{1,1}$ domain and let $X$ be a Markov process in $\Omega$. My question is regarding the existence of the Green function and Martin kernel of $X$.

Let $X$ be a symmetric $2\alpha$-stable process and $X^\Omega$ the subprocess of $X$ killed upon leaving $\Omega$. It is well-known that the infnitesimal-generator of $X^{\Omega}$ is the (restricted) fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^{\alpha}$. The existence of Green function $G^{\Omega}$ and Martin kernel $M^{\Omega}$ of $X$ are established in *Estimates on Green functions and Poisson kernels for symmetric stable processes* https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002080050232.
Furthermore, the joint limit
$$ \lim_{ (x,y) \to (x_0,z_0)} \frac{G^\Omega_X(x,y)}{G^\Omega_X(x_0,y)},\quad x_0 \in \Omega, z_0 \in \partial \Omega$$
exists.

Now we consider a censored $2\alpha$-stable process $Y^{\Omega}$ whose infinitesimal-generator is the regional fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta_\Omega)^\alpha$. It is also known that for every reference point $x_0 \in \Omega$ and $x \in \Omega$, the limit
$$ M^\Omega(x,z_0):=\lim_{ y \to z_0} \frac{G^\Omega_Y(x,y)}{G^\Omega_Y(x_0,y)}, \quad z_0 \in \partial \Omega$$ exists, which is again the Martin kernel of $Y^\Omega$.

My question is whether the joint limit
$$ \lim_{ (x,y) \to (x_0,z_0)} \frac{G^\Omega_Y(x,y)}{G^\Omega_Y(x_0,y)},\quad x_0 \in \Omega, z_0 \in \partial \Omega$$
exists, like in the case of $X$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you evaluate the limit as $x \to x_0$ with $x_0$ the same as the reference point for the definition of the Martin kernel? Anyway, the answer is likely "yes", this should follow in a rather straightforward way from some Harnack-type inequalities.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Actually, I need to show the existence of the joint limit $G^{\Omega}(x,y)d(y)^{1-2\alpha}$ as $(x,y) \to (x_0,z_0)$, therefore the limit with the reference point that I mentioned above is enough.

 Could you explain this a bit more? I have to admit that I am working in the field of classical PDEs and therefore I am not really familiar of the techniques using probabilistic approaches, like in your papers, as well as Bogdan's, Chen's, Vondráček's etc.

Answer (score 1):

I do know a reference for this particular result — although I am completely sure it is true!

The original Bogdan–Burdzy–Chen paper does not even provide a complete proof of the existence of the boundary limit. Instead, it refers to the case of usual fractional Laplacian. The proof of joint convergence is also very similar to the corresponding one for the usual fractional Laplacian, but I understand this is not sufficient for your needs.

Technically, you can refer to my paper with Tomasz Juszczyszyn, [DOI:10.1007/s11118-017-9616-z](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11118-017-9616-z). Remarks 3 and 4 there seem to address your question in a much greater generality. This is still somewhat awkward (one reuses the boundary result for an interior point to get equicontinuity of harmonic functions), but at least it does not seem to involve any hand-waving.

I guess one can find an even better reference in one of the papers by Panki Kim, Renming Song and Zoran Vondraček, but unfortunately I do not have enough time to search it now.

Comment: Thank you very much for kind answer. I hope that I could get some ideas from your paper. Before posting this, I also believed that this result holds true for a class of Markov processes. At least in the case of subordinate killed Brownian motion, I could prove the existence of joint limit via the Dirichlet heat kernel of the Laplacian. However, I could not find such result for other processes in any paper by the mentioned authors. I guess this is because for the existence of Martin kernel, one only needs the existence of pointwise limit for every $x \in \Omega$.

Comment: For "nice" processes it is indeed sufficient to have a pointwise boundary limit, because harmonic functions are equicontinuous and so joint continuity follows. This equicontinuity is part of folklore in the probability crowd, and it is proved rigorously and in a more general setting in the PDE literature under the name "interior regularity". For general processes, however, the best one can have is, I think, lower semi-continuity (plus fine-continuity) — at least this is what Proposition 14.3 in Chung–Walsh book seems to suggest.